# MongoDB find() won't find what I need

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to find a document in a collection. I have been using this query structure on nearly all my collections, but for some reason this isnt working for this collection. Any help?

The only data in this collection right now
`[ { _id: 581757143389e565b5cf8124,
    companyProfileID: '86660a5b-7f61-4238-889d-1cc3087947b9',
    url: 'sentsoftware.com',
    appID: 1 } ]`

Query Structure:

```js
function getCompany(companyUrl, app, callback) {
 MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) {
   console.log(err);
  } else {
   console.log("We are connected");
  }
  
  var collection = db.collection('Companies');
  collection.find({url: companyUrl, appID: app}).toArray(function (err, result) {
   if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    callback(err);
   } else if (result.length) {
    console.log("found");
    callback(result);
   } else {
    console.log("No document found");
    callback(err);
   }
  });
 });
}
```

I keep getting No document found. But if i were to take out the `, appID: app` part, it finds the document.

Comment: Are you passing `app` as a `Number`? That's how it's stored in the database.

Comment: Perhaps it's a string versus number problem. Are you searching for 1 or "1"

Comment: Yes I am passing it as a number. I changed it to a string and it immediately found it. Thank you! Someone post as answer and Ill accept it

Comment: After you @robertklep sir.

Comment: @MatthewWilcoxson no no, after you! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Mongo query is type specific (although numbers can be cast), you've likely got a string where you are expecting a number.

If you ask for the string "1",

```
collection.find({appID: "1"})
```

it will only return documents with a *string* equal to "1", if you ask for the number 1

```
collection.find({appID: 1})
```

it will only return documents with a real *number* (Double, Long, Int) in.

You can check which types you have with a $type query:

```
collection.find( { appID : { $type : "string" } } ); // or type 2 for earlier mongo versions
collection.find( { appID : { $type : "double" } } ); // or type 1 for earlier mongo versions
collection.find( { appID : { $type : "int" } } ); // or type 16 for earlier mongo versions
```

Check out the BSON types and $type in the docs, currently (2016/11/11): https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/#op._S_type

Interestingly it *will* cast between Doubles, Longs and Ints; so inserting these:

```
db.collection("temp").insertOne({ "type" : "my double", "num" : new mongo.Double(1.0) });
db.collection("temp").insertOne({ "type" : "my long", "num" : new mongo.Long(1) });
db.collection("temp").insertOne({ "type" : "my int", "num" : 1 });
```

and searching for:

```
{ "num" : 1 }
```

returns the three documents.